# How do I change my website's font on Github Pages?

Tags: html, fonts

I am completely new to website design and programming. I have created a website on Mobirise, and am storing it on Github. I am looking to change the font across the website, as I no longer like the one that I had chosen on Mobirise when I exported it to Github.

I have uploaded the font files that I would need to use to the /OpenSansFonts folder in my repository at: https://github.com/SkyBetChampionship/Sky-Bet-Championship/tree/gh-pages.

Would anybody please be able to advise me what to do next to change the font across my website?

Thank you in advance,

Adam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create separate *.css file with this code, or add this code in your **assets/mobirise/css/mbr-additional.css** (if you create separate file, don't forget import this file in your home.html.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'OpenSans-Light';
    src: url('/OpenSansFonts/OpenSans-Light.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: 300;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'OpenSans-Light';
    src: url('/OpenSansFonts/OpenSans-LightItalic.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: 300;
    font-style: italic;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'OpenSans';
    src: url('/OpenSansFonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'OpenSans';
    src: url('/OpenSansFonts/OpenSans-RegularItalic.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: italic;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'OpenSans-Semibold';
    src: url('/OpenSansFonts/OpenSans-SemiBold.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: 600;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'OpenSans-SemiBold';
    src: url('/OpenSansFonts/OpenSans-SemiBoldItalic.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: 600;
    font-style: italic;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'OpenSans';
    src: url('/OpenSansFonts/OpenSans-Bold.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: 700;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'OpenSans';
    src: url('/OpenSansFonts/OpenSans-BoldItalic.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: 700;
    font-style: italic;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'OpenSans';
    src: url('/OpenSansFonts/OpenSans-ExtraBold.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: 800;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'OpenSans';
    src: url('/OpenSansFonts/OpenSans-ExtraBoldItalic.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: 800;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

For change font across web site, add to **body** in assets/mobirise/css/mbr-additional.css **font-family** property.

```
body {
  font-family: 'OpenSans';
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
```

For import separate css file with fonts, add in your home.html around 42 string this code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="your_path_to_file/file_with_fonts.css" type="text/css">
```

When you want another style of font, use **font-family**, **font-weight** and **font-style** properties.

Feel free ask other questions :) Hope this will help you